# change html just before it leaves the code-behind

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

In vb.net or C# web sites

How do I access the final html just before it leaves the server so that I can make a final html tweaks from the code-behind.( I don't want to use JavaScript to make these adjustments)

Will it be the page PreRenderComplete event that will be the last event that fires that I will be able to see the html that is sent to the browser which I will be able to edit the html with HtmlAgilityPack?

This must be easy to do and possible

Thanks

Comment: Form_Load event makes all the decisions before it render HTML to the client. What do you want to change?

Comment: I want to add a div at a specific location

Comment: Use <asp:literal id="mydiv" runat="server"></asp:literal> where you want to put the div. In Form_Loadevent, mydiv.Text = "<div><p>This is the content I want to add.</p></div>".

Comment: thanks. I know about that -  I was hoping that just before the html leaves the code-behind I code access it -  after al the controls are rendered  -- at he end... this must be possible = maybe i want to clean the html... thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I just wanted to share what I came up with after  reading  the responses to my post and doing some searching online and with reference to this forum post here http://forums.asp.net/t/1146098.aspx/1  and using HtmlAggilityPack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Here is the code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)

        Dim mem As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim twr As New System.IO.StreamWriter(mem)
        Dim myWriter As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(twr)
        MyBase.Render(myWriter)

        myWriter.Flush()
        myWriter.Dispose()

        Dim strmRdr As New System.IO.StreamReader(mem)
        strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0
        Dim pageContent As String = strmRdr.ReadToEnd()
        strmRdr.Dispose()
        mem.Dispose()

        writer.Write(AlterWithHTMLAGP(pageContent))


    End Sub



    Function AlterWithHTMLAGP(ByVal pageSource As String) As String

        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()

        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True

        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageSource)

        Dim newNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div>" & "someHtml" & "</div>")

        Dim body As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")

        body.PrependChild(newNode)


        Return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteTo()

    End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying already written out HTML is at least not trivial (if not impssible). The response is beeing written to output stream that may very well be already partially sent to client.

It would be much easier to manipulate controls tree and insert elements there before it is rendered (PreRenderComplete sounds righ) if you are usign WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `Page_Render` and easily intercept the output stream. There is no risk in doing this. In any `Page`:

```
 protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)         
 {
      // intercept the output stream and write to your own 
      // StringWriter, bound to a StringBuilder

      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
      base.Render(sw);

      string html = sb.ToString();

      // do stuff to alter "html"

      ..

      // write it to the real output stream

      writer.Write(html)
 }
```

If you are using `UpdatePanels` (async postbacks) it can get a little hairy because the HTML is formatted in a special way. Even there, it's not impossible to alter, but it requires more work because there's actually a checksum in the UpdatePanel data blocks. (Fortunately it's a very simple one, just the length of the content). But not quite as simple as just changing the content and writing it back.

But for non-async postbacks it looks like any other HTML page, alter it to your heart's content.